# Passing Integer Between Activities and Intents in Android Is Always Resulting in Zero / Null

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, bundle, android-intent

I'm attempting to pass two integers from my Main Page activity (a latitude and longitude) to a second activity that contains an instance of Google Maps that will place a marker at the lat and long provided.  My conundrum is that when I retrieve the bundle in the Map_Page activity the integers I passed are always 0, which is the default when they are Null.  Does anyone see anything glaringly wrong?

I have the following stored in a button click OnClick method.

```
Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();

dataBundle.putInt("LatValue", 39485000);
dataBundle.putInt("LongValue", -80142777);
Intent myIntent = new Intent();
myIntent.setClassName("com.name.tlc", "com.name.tlc.map_page");
myIntent.putExtras(dataBundle);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

---

Then in my map_page activity I have the following in onCreate to pick up the data.

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
System.out.println("Get Intent done");
if(extras !=null)
{
    System.out.println("Let's get the values");
    int latValue = extras.getInt("latValue");
    int longValue = extras.getInt("longValue");

    System.out.println("latValue = " + latValue + " longValue = " + longValue);

}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
System.out.println("Let's get the values");
int latValue = extras.getInt("latValue");
int longValue = extras.getInt("longValue");
```

Not the same as

```
myIntent.putExtra("LatValue", (int)39485000);
myIntent.putExtra("LongValue", (int)-80142777);
```

Also it might be because you do not keep the name of the Int exactly the same throughout your code. Java and the Android SDK are Case-sensitive

Comment: The values are case-sensitive so Taranasus is correct - you're using two different names to set/get them.

Comment: I am the epitome of /facepalm.  At least I can be relieved that it was a silly mistake on my part.  Appreciate the alert. Would have taken me a long time to notice that.

Answer (score 20):

Geeklat,

You don't need to use Bundle in this case.

Do your puts like this...

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent();
myIntent.setClassName("com.name.tlc", "com.name.tlc.map_page");
myIntent.putExtra("LatValue", (int)39485000);
myIntent.putExtra("LongValue", (int)-80142777);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Then you can retrieve them with...

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
int latValue = extras.getInt("LatValue");
int longValue = extras.getInt("LongValue");
```

Comment: I originally had it this way, but changed it trying to find what was wrong.