# get listitem position and pass it to another activity (android php)

Tags: php, android, listview

i have this code that retrive list item from a database by php code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {
    // Progress Dialog 
    private ProgressDialog pDialog; 
    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> DaftarRS; 
    // url daftar rumah sakit 
    private static String url_daftar_rs = "http://www.iagstore.net/nangnur/daftar_rumah_sakit.php"; 
    // JSON Node names 
    public static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    public static final String TAG_DAFTAR_RS = "daftar_rs"; 
    public static final String TAG_ID_RS = "id_rs"; 
    public static final String TAG_NAMA_RS = "nama_rs"; 
    public static final String TAG_LINK_IMAGE_RS = "link_image_rs";
    public static final String TAG_ALAMAT_RS = "alamat_rs";
    public static final String TAG_TELEPON_RS = "telepon_rs"; 
    Button ButttonInputRumahSakit; 
    // daftar_rs JSONArray 
    JSONArray daftar_rs = null; ListView list; ListAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Hashmap for ListView
        DaftarRS = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        // Loading daftar rumah sakit in Background Thread
        new LoadDaftarRumahSakitActivity().execute();
        // Get listview
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }

    /** * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView * */
    public void SetListViewAdapter(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> daftar) {
        adapter = new ListAdapter(this, daftar);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    { super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // if result code 100 
    if (resultCode == 100) { 
        // if result code 100 is received // means user edited/deleted record
        // reload this screen again 
        Intent intent = getIntent(); finish(); 
        startActivity(intent); } } 
    /** * Background Async Task to Load all record data by making HTTP Request * */
    class LoadDaftarRumahSakitActivity extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /** * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog * */
        @Override protected void onPreExecute() { super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Mohon tunggu...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show(); }
        /** * getting All record data from url * */ 
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) { 
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(); 
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_daftar_rs, "GET", params);
            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("Daftar Rumah Sakit: ", json.toString()); try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG 
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS); 
                if (success == 1) { 
                    // Ada record Data (SUCCESS = 1) 
                    // Getting Array of daftar_rs 
                    daftar_rs = json.getJSONArray(TAG_DAFTAR_RS);
                    // looping through All daftar_rs 
                    for (int i = 0; i < daftar_rs.length(); i++) { JSONObject c = daftar_rs.getJSONObject(i); 
                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id_rs = c.getString(TAG_ID_RS); 
                    String nama_rs = c.getString(TAG_NAMA_RS); 
                    String link_image_rs = c.getString(TAG_LINK_IMAGE_RS);
                    String alamat_rs = c.getString(TAG_ALAMAT_RS); 
                    String telepon_rs = c.getString(TAG_TELEPON_RS);
                    // creating new HashMap 
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_ID_RS, id_rs); map.put(TAG_NAMA_RS, nama_rs); 
                    map.put(TAG_LINK_IMAGE_RS, link_image_rs); 
                    map.put(TAG_ALAMAT_RS, alamat_rs);
                    map.put(TAG_TELEPON_RS, telepon_rs);
                    // adding HashList to ArrayList 
                    DaftarRS.add(map);
} } else {
    // Tidak Ada Record Data (SUCCESS = 0) 
    // Akan menutup aplikasi 
    finish(); } } catch (JSONException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } return null;
    } 
        /** * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog * **/ 
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) { 
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all record rumah sakit
            pDialog.dismiss(); // updating UI from Background Thread 
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { public void run() { 
                // updating listview 
                SetListViewAdapter(DaftarRS); 
            } }); } }
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // Cant Figure it out!!!!!!!!!!!
        ??????
                ???????
                 ??????

    } }
```

could you please guide me how to get list position and pass to another activity?
i know that i should use putExtra methode but i have use it and always pass the first item to the next activity

Comment: The third arguments of onItemClick is the position of the item clicked. Do you want to start a another activity when clicked? If so, place this position in the intent using  putExtra (String name, int value) and can get this value in the other activity using getextras. Pls check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424135/passing-integer-between-activities-and-intents-in-android-is-always-resulting-in

Comment: [code]
@Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TrackListActivity.class);
        
        // send album id to tracklist activity to get list of songs under that album
String id_rss = null;
i.putExtra(id_rss, arg3)      ;

        startActivity(i);
 }
[code]
like this?????

Comment: onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TrackListActivity.class); // send album id to tracklist activity to get list of songs under that album  i.putExtra("position", arg3) ; startActivity(i); } and in the TrackListActivity, in OnCreate() you can use getBundle and then getExtra with the string "position".