# get Integer variable from other activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse, integer

```
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        public void onClick(View v)
        {

            numberPicker1int = Integer.parseInt(numberPicker1.getContext().toString());
            numberPicker2int = Integer.parseInt(numberPicker2.getContext().toString());
            value1=numberPicker1int;
            value2=numberPicker2int;
   }
        });
```

value1 and value2 in other activity(MainActivity). how i get value1(int) and value2(int)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424135/passing-integer-between-activities-and-intents-in-android-is-always-resulting-in

Answer (score 1):

In main activity:

`Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("value1",value1);
                intent.putExtra("value2",value2);
                startActivity(intent);`

In your secondary Activity where you want to have acess to the values:

```
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    int value1 = bundle.getInt("value1");
    int value2 = bundle.getInt("value2");
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly then you could declare two instance variables:

```
Private value1 As Integer
Private value2 As Integer
```

Then you can create two properties to get the values.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the value in a bundle when starting your other activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
int myValue1 = 23213;
int myValue2 = 21223;
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putInt("value1", myValue1);
b.putInt("value2", myValue2);
intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);
```

In your second Activity you get these values:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
int myValue1 = b.getInt("value1", 0);
int myValue2 = b.getInt("value2", 0);
```